# What happened to the words' size

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile, top-answers

I was frantically searching for my profile page link when I came across this.

[image: !]

Don't you think the question "Are secret hats limited to..." is getting all the spotlight?

I'm using Safari for iPhone. I'm viewing the full site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug of SE, but there is such a feature ("special abilities") on iPhones and Android phones which adapts the paragraph size (on click?).

<sup>and btw, where have you seen see a mobile version of network profile? There is no need to mention "full site" :D</sup>

Comment: Not sure this is accurate - no idea why iOS or Android would do that seemingly at random without any action on the user's part. I can reproduce this, and it's weird. I could see short titles that get enlarged, which would at least theoretically be useful, but there doesn't seem to be a pattern I can discern.

Comment: @AnnaLear It's mobile WebKit's "font boosting" feature. It increases the font size on wider blocks of text when the viewport is way larger than the device's viewport.

Comment: @Anna is mobile Safari supported at all by SE?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Within reason. :)